# 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for

Tags: ios, multithreading, testing, core-data, xctest

I'm seeing some bizarre behaviour in a test. This error appears only on the second test run and after. At the end of each test, I delete the Core Data objects I've created during the test. If I comment out the cleanup, and don't delete the test objects, I don't seem to get the error.

This sort of matches up with the descriptions of this error I've read elsewhere. What's weird is this doesn't seem particularly related to threading (it occurs across test-runs). I've gone so far as to look at the sqlite tables my test leaves behind. The test leaves the database in largely the same state it found it in, so it's really hard for me to see what this error is upset about. What other state does Core Data keep in this regard, and how can I examine it?

If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: Are there dependencies between the tests? Are you sharing the managedObjectContext between tests? I guess some code examples would help. You might also consider using an in-memory store for testing instead of writing to disk so you don't have to do cleanup. Each test can use a fresh store. That is the approach I use and it seems to work pretty well.

Comment: There are no dependencies between tests, and the entire stack is reinstantiated between tests I believe. It's very weird. I've gotten rid of the problem by adopting a different approach in the code under test... but I'd still be really interested in what could cause this nonsense! :D I was thinking about code examples, but it's fairly complex; I think I'd need pages of them to paint a proper picture. Essentially I've got an event-driven (NSNotification) architecture from network calls, which indirectly trigger Core Data updates.

Comment: This issue is related to having a "dangling" instance of `NSManagedObject` , which has already been deleted in the persistent store. Without showing at least a bit of your code in which the exception occurs, it's hard to guess what was wrong. And as @MikeTaverne said, it's a good idea to use in-memory store for unit test to make them deterministic and independent on each other.